# select into a temporary table in ms sql query if else block

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I need to pull an additional list of items during certain months. This is a simplified version.

I had thought it might be the blocking, so I added the BEGIN/END blocks, I made sure to drop the temp table at the start and end of my code. I'm a bit puzzled why it seems to try to read lines in the part of the ELSE that does not apply.

This is the whole sample code

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TheTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TheTempTable

IF DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) IN (N'March', N'April')

BEGIN
        SELECT PartNumber 
        INTO #TheTempTable  -- If I comment this out when May this block works
        FROM MainPartsTable
    UNION
        SELECT '999'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
        SELECT PartNumber 
        INTO #TheTempTable --this works for March if this line is commmented out
        FROM MainPartsTable
END

SELECT * FROM #TheTempTable

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TheTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TheTempTable
```

Running as is I get this error message complaining about the INTO #TheTempTable in the second block:

```
There is already an object named '#TheTempTable' in the database.
```

It doesn't work unless I comment out this line in the second block

```
INTO #TheTempTable --this works for March when this line is commented out
```

If I change the month to May it only works if I comment out the INTO #TheTempTable in the first block

```
IF DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) IN (N'May', N'April')
```

Thank You!

Comment: Notice how Larnu used `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`? Learn the significant difference. Also notice the use of DATEPART (MONTH is the shorter equivalent) to avoid a dependence on language. Lastly, do you REALLY need a temp table at all? This type of <select into x, do something with x> pattern is often overkill or inefficient.

Comment: It *can* be, @SMor, but that doesn't mean it will be. It depends on it's use case. Though for the simplistic query we have here, I agree it is unlikely to be a performance benefit.

Comment: @Larnu and that is why i phrased it conditionally. That is not an absolute statement but it is quite a common problem based on the questions posted here. Blindly using a pattern - any pattern - is not a good habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a parser issue. You have 2 statements that attempt to create the object `#TheTempTable` in your batch. It doesn't matter that the 2 statements cannot be both be reached, the parser isn't "that clever". This can be replicated with this simple batch:

```sql
IF 1 = 1 
    SELECT 1 AS I INTO #T
ELSE
    SELECT 2 AS I INTO #T;
```

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> There is already an object named '#T' in the database.

Instead, create the table outside of your `IF` statements, and then `INSERT` into it:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TheTempTable

SELECT PartNumber
INTO #TheTempTable
FROM MainPartsTable
WHERE 1 = 0; --Never true

IF DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) IN (N'March', N'April')
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TheTempTable (PartNumber)
        SELECT PartNumber 
        FROM MainPartsTable
        UNION ---ALL?
        SELECT '999';
END;
ELSE 
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #TheTempTable (PartNumber)
        SELECT PartNumber 
        FROM MainPartsTable
END;

SELECT * FROM #TheTempTable;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TheTempTable;
```

Of course, the entire thing could be simplified to the below:

```sql
SELECT PartNumber
INTO #TheTempTable
FROM(SELECT PartNumber 
     FROM MainPartsTable
     UNION ALL
     SELECT '999'
     WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) IN (3,4))PN; --Language agnostic
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had just realized I needed the INSERT INTO bit. Appreciate the suggestion on the simplified version. I'll look into that! Thank you again!